# Why is splitting my MySQL statement into two separate queries faster?

Tags: mysql

Our team identified a particular query as being very slow on our system. In analyzing it, one of columns was indexed, while the other was not.

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE device SET isChanged = 1 WHERE deviceTemplateId = 154 or customTemplateId = 154
```

customTemplateId was the one that wasn't indexed. So we fixed that by adding the index.

Then, we benchmarked the query with the index as written above against this split version below:

```
UPDATE device SET isChanged = 1 WHERE deviceTemplateId = 154;
UPDATE device SET isChanged = 1 WHERE customTemplateId = 154;
```

Here are the stats from 63 runs of 200 sets of queries each:

```
          Consol    Split
Min       1.4164    1.4014
Max       3.2345    2.7476
Median    1.57425   1.54275
```

So while the difference seems marginal, what is the reason that the split queries run faster than the single statement?

Comment: Check the query plans first to see what they say the database is doing.

Comment: It should be `LIKE '%..'` not `= '%..'`. Also, `Like '%..'` is not able to use index; while `Like '..%'` can.

Comment: @Madhur- that's straight from a sprintf(), not actual values. I'll edit it for clarity.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen what do you mean by 'query plans'? Please forgive, I'm new to mysql performance analysis.

Comment: You can use `EXPLAIN` to get a description of what the database is doing. Since it always depends on the data and statistics etc without that it’s very hard to say what’s happening. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, ah gotcha. We're having a hard time with that one actually because in the version of MySQL we're using, the EXPLAIN doesn't actually handle WHEREs yet! lol (Eventually management will allow us to upgrade..........)

Comment: You can get an appropriatly close explain plan if you do a `select` instead of an `update`. But your timings indicate that your MySQL is doing an index merge (otherwise the combined query would be significantly slower), so the explain plans will probably not reveal anything important. Have you considered rerunning your measurement? 2% deviation seems insignificant enough that another run might make the splitted queries look slower.